# My state changes when the component is re-rendered

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a web app that fetches recipe from a backend API. When the `feed` component mounts, I set an axios get method to receive data from the API and update my redux store and then update the components state to the props matched to state of the redux store using mapPropsToState.
It works when the component is rendered initially, but moving to another component, say `Create Recipe` and then switching back to the `Feed` component, the content flashes for a mini second ad then disappears. And shows 'No Recipes To Show' which is what I set to display when there are no recipes.

I have tried using the setState in the componentDidMount method and then also in the .then method of axios, and also in both, simultaneously. Still same result. I have also tried logging the state to the console and it shows that it received the data well all the times that I switched back and forth between components, but the data wont display on screen.

```
FEED.JS


import React, {Component} from 'react';
import RecipeCard from './RecipeCard';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {updateRecipes} from '../actions/recipeActions'
import axios from 'axios'

class Feed extends Component {
state = {
    recipes: []
};

feedTitleStyle = {
    color: 'rgba(230, 126, 34, 1)',
    margin: '28px 0'
};

componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/recipes/')
        .then(res =>{
            console.log(res);
            this.props.updateRecipesFromAPI(res.data);
            this.setState({
                recipes: this.props.recipes
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        });
    let recipes = [...this.state.recipes, this.props.recipes];
    this.setState({
        recipes
    })

}


render() {

    const {recipes} = this.state;
    console.log(this.props.recipes);
    console.log(recipes);
    const recipesList = recipes.length ? (
        recipes.map(recipe => {
            return (
                <div className="container" key={recipe.id}>
                    <div className='col-md-10 md-offset-1 col-lg-9 mx-auto'>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col s12 m7">
                                <RecipeCard recipe={recipe}/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        })
    ) : (
        <div className='center'>No recipes yet</div>
    );
    return (
       <div>
           <div className='container'>
               <h4 style={this.feedTitleStyle} className='center feed-title'>Feed</h4>
               {recipesList}
           </div>
       </div>
    )
}
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return{
        recipes: state.recipes
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
return {
    updateRecipesFromAPI: (recipes) => {dispatch({
    type: 'UPDATE_RECIPES',
    recipes
}}
}
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Feed)
```

Here is my reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  recipes: [],
};

const recipeReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'UPDATE_RECIPES':
            let updatedRecipes = [...state.recipes, action.recipes];
            console.log(updatedRecipes[0]);
        return {
                ...state,
                recipes: updatedRecipes[0]
            };
        default:
            return state
    }
};

export default recipeReducer
```

Comment: did you try moving the axios call to the constuctor. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

Comment: What's the reason to use both Redux and local state? If there's no good reason, consider solving this entirely in Redux.

Comment: Thanks @estus, this totally worked. I also used thunk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are juggling between **REDUX** and **State** which is wrong, you should not be doing this, instead, the ideal solution would be to stick on with REDUX and let REDUX do the async call and fill in the **store**, and make use of the `mapStateToProps` to get it into props.

use **Action Creators** ( Async ) to solve this, you should be using middleware like **thunk** ([Thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk)) to do this.

**Action creators:**

```
export const updateRecipesFromAPI_Async = () => { // async action creator
    return dispatch => {
        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/recipes/')
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);
                dispatch(updateRecipesFromAPI_Success(response.data.name, orderData)); // calls a sync action creator
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
}

export const updateRecipesFromAPI_Success = (recipes) => { // sync action creator
    return {
        type: 'UPDATE_RECIPES',
        orderData: recipes
    }
}
```

Comment: Happy to help :)